# Combine multiple Retrofit Observable dynamically

Tags: android, system.reactive, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I have a list of Observables like so:

```
 List<Observable<MyObj>> listObservables = new ArrayList<Observable<MyObj>>();
```

I'd like to combine all Observable in a single one, I can handle it if I know the number of Observable using `zip()`, for example we have 3 Observable:

```
 Observable<MyObj1> obs1= MyRestClient.getSomeData1();
 Observable<MyObj2> obs2= MyRestClient.getSomeData2();
 Observable<MyObj3> obs3= MyRestClient.getSomeData3();
```

I have a wrapper obj:

```
class MyWrapperObj {
    private MyObj1 onj1;
    private MyObj2 onj2;
    private MyObj3 onj3;

    public MyWrapperObj(MyObj1 onj1, MyObj2 onj2, MyObj3 onj3) {
        this.onj1 = onj1;
        this.onj2 = onj2;
        this.onj3 = onj3;
    }
}
```

So I can combine them like so:

```
 Observable<MyWrapperObj> combinedObservable = Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, obs3, new Func3<MyObj1, MyObj2, MyObj3, MyWrapperObj>() {
        @Override
        public MyWrapperObj call(MyObj1 obj1, MyObj2 obj2, MyObj3 obj3) {
            return new MyWrapperObj(obj1, obj2, obj3);
        }
    });

    combinedObservable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<MyWrapperObj>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {                       
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(MyWrapperObj wrapperObj) {
                }
            });
```

Everything is working fine, so my problem is how to organize this combination to be for n Observable?

**RESPONSE**

as @maciekjanusz mentioned in it's answer I did:

```
  Observable<MyWrapperObj> combinedObservable = Observable.zip(listObservables, new FuncN<MyWrapperObj>() {
        @Override
        public MyWrapperObjcall(Object... args) {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to `zip` **n** Observables, put them in a list and apply the `public static <R> Observable<R> zip(@NotNull java.lang.Iterable<? extends Observable<?>> ws, rx.functions.FuncN<? extends R> zipFunction)` factory method.

```
List<Observable<String>> observables = Arrays.asList(Observable.just("String 1"), Observable.just("String 2"));

Observable.zip(observables, args -> {
    // put your zipping code here
});
```

For example, if you want to create a list of strings for each emission from all observables:

```
Observable.zip(observables, Arrays::asList);
```

Or, if using RxJava on android without retrolambda:

```
Observable.zip(observables, args -> Arrays.asList(args));
```

Comment: what do you mean by `zipping code`? I need to receive a list of `MyObj` as final response of Observable

Comment: then my example `Observable.zip(observables, Arrays::asList);` will do exactly that if `observables` is of type `Iterable<Observable<MyObj>>`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the list:

```
List<Observable<MyObj>> listObservables
```

You might consider using  [`Observable.concatDelayError`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java#L1475)

The advantage if it is finishing all `Obbservable`'s even if any of them finishes with error (resulting in an error in such case).

Remember, that every `Observable` in this sequence must return the result to `onNext` method of `Subscriber`. The result also must have the same type.

Example:

```
Observable.concatDelayError(listObservables);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until all observables is complete by using 
.zip(observable1, ..., observableN, funcN).first() operators. There is an overload, accepting Observable> argument (as in FlatMap).

First overload takes Iterable> - you can pass list of observables of arbitrary size and second argument - FuncN - receives list of values.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know n, it can be 1-10 so I can't set FunN

Comment: first overload takes Iterable<Observable<>> and FuncN, so you can pass list of observables

Comment: and FuncN<R> receives array of arguments.